# JMeter "if controller" with parameters?

Tags: jmeter

I was reading the [JMeter documentation](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) and came across this info box about "If Controllers":

> No variables are made available to the script when the condition is interpreted as Javascript. If you need access to such variables, then select "Interpret Condition as Variable Expression?" and use a __javaScript() function call. You can then use the objects "vars", "log", "ctx" etc. in the script.

I don't quite follow this. Does this mean if I want access to a "User Defined Parameter" then I can access it only by writing some JavaScript? The example that follows this box then refers to "${COUNT}"

Could someone clarify the usage of the If Controller, maybe with an example or two?

Comment: Date.now() - ${__property(lastUpdateTimeMS)} > 900000

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can simply use something like

```
${my_variable}=='1'
```

Sometimes JMeter documentation can be confusing :)

**Edit 27 september 2017:**

The answer here works but **has a very bad performance impact when number of threads exceeds 40.**

See below for correct and most performing answer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/46976447/460802

See:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61675

Comment: Thanks. Other things I noticed: Above expression works with or without quotes. To compare strings, user defined variable value must be double quoted. If unquoted boolean used (true/false) in UDV, the variable can be used by itself as the condition (i.e. MY_VAR=true, if ${MY_VAR} then)

Comment: Actually I took my example code from a working project, where I check for the string '1'.But maybe it's because it's a char that it works with single quotes?

Comment: OK, more info on String matching. Suppose MY_VAR = apples. ${MY_VAR} == "apples" # => returns false. "${MY_VAR}" == "apples" # => returns true. Suppose MY_VAR = "apples". ${MY_VAR} == "apples" # => returns true. "${MY_VAR}" == "apples" # => returns false. If you set a variable in a BeanShell, vars.put("MY_VAR","apples"); then you are in first case. You could do vars.put("MY_VAR","\"apples\""); but you're probably better off just putting the variable name in quotes for an If Controller string comparison.

Answer (score 37):

All these answers are wrong! You need to put the variable reference in quotes, like so:

```
"${my_variable}"=="foo"
```

Answer (score 14):

If Controller will internally use javascript to evaluate the condition but this can have a performance penalty.

A better option (default one starting from JMeter 4, see https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61675) is to check "**Interpret Condition as Variable Expression?**", then in the condition field you have 2 options:

- Option 1 : Use a variable that contains true or false. For example If you want to test if last sample was successful, you can use

> ${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}

[image: If Controller starting with JMeter 3.4]

or any variable you want that contains true/false

> ${myVar}

- Option 2 : Use a function (${[__jexl3](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3)()} is advised) to evaluate an expression that must return true or false. 
  For example if COUNT is equal to 1:

> ${__jexl3("${COUNT}"== "1",)}

OR

> ${__jexl3(${COUNT}== 1,)}

[image: If Controller with expression starting with JMeter 3.4]

Starting with 4.0, if you don't use the "Interpret Condition as Variable Expression?", a warning in RED will be displayed:

[image: If Controller using javascript in JMeter 3.4]

If you'd like to learn more about JMeter and performance testing this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) can help you.

Answer (score 13):

**UNCHECK the CHECKBOX
"Interpret condition as variable expression"**

I wasted a couple of hours without unchecking this checkbox. It worked with and without semicolon(;) at the end of the statement. Make sure that you have set the User-Defined Variables before calling the if controller.

All the following variations worked for me in Jakarta Jmeter 1.5

- ${__javaScript("${HOMEPAGE}"=="Y")}
- ${__javaScript("${HOMEPAGE}"=="Y")};
- "${HOMEPAGE}"=="Y"
- "${HOMEPAGE}"=="Y";

Answer (score 8):

God bless the http://habrahabr.ru 
Have tried until found these. [image]

Using the quotes was my solution.

Answer (score 5):

As Gerrie said you need to check your variable

```
${my_var} == 'value'
```

But be careful with the '[User Defined Variables](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables)'

> Note that all the UDV elements in a
>   test plan - no matter where they are -
>   are processed at the start.

That basically means that you cannot define 'User Defined Variables' inside an 'If Controller'. Take a look to the 'BeanShell' instead.

Answer (score 3):

Replace:
${my_variable}=='1'
with
"${my_variable}" == "1"

Answer (score 1):

if it's string value pass as below and its performance effective

${__groovy("${key}"=="value")}

Answer (score 0):

[image: Check the image]

I have used `${code_g1}== 200` in condition and it worked for me.